# Split Date and time variable with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, datetime, dplyr, sparklyr

I'm trying to deal with a date and time variable (dttm) in a spark data frame. I'm using sparklyr and dplyr. Here is my issue...

Each row of the column in question is in this format:

- 2018-06-11 22:06:45

I want to split this date and time column (dttm) into two columns :

- the first one with the date : 2018-06-11 (yyyy-mm-dd)
- the second one with the time : 22:06:45 (hh:mm:ss)

So in the first place, I used regexp_replace and mutate to create the time column :

```
spark_df %>% mutate(time = regexp_replace(date_and_time, "^[^_]* ", ""))
```

Here is what I obtain in my new column "time":

- 00:06:45

So the code is nearly working, the only issue is that the two first digit are converting in 00.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be a good starting point if it doesn't solve your problem.

```
dates <- data.frame(date = 
    c("2018-06-11 22:06:45", "2018-06-11 22:07:45", "2019-06-11 22:06:45"))
tbl <- copy_to(sc, dates)

tbl %>% mutate(new_date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>%
    mutate(day = as.Date(new_date), 
    time = paste0(hour(new_date), ":", minute(new_date), ":",
                       second(new_date))) 

#   date                new_date            day        time
#   <chr>               <dttm>              <date>     <chr>
# 1 2018-06-11 22:06:45 2018-06-11 12:06:45 2018-06-11 22:6:45
# 2 2018-06-11 22:07:45 2018-06-11 12:07:45 2018-06-11 22:7:45
# 3 2019-06-11 22:06:45 2019-06-11 12:06:45 2019-06-11 22:6:45
```